# Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: selectedOneMenue

Tags: jsf-2.2

I am trying to test the working of the`f:selectedOneMenue` tag but when running the code on the server I am getting the error underneath.

I just want to show the content of the `food` arrayList in the ContactBeanTwo as a select button so that the user can select some of the item. As a result, the item will show in the message area underneath.

How can I manage it to work?

I appreciate any help.

**error**

```
2016-07-09T17:57:15.656+0200|Warnung: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: /index49_select_tags.xhtml @19,58 <f:selectedOneMenue> Tag Library supports namespace: http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: selectedOneMenue
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationManager.pushTag(CompilationManager.java:311)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler$CompilationHandler.startElement(SAXCompiler.java:266)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:745)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2787)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:454)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:430)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:481)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$100(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$1.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:295)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1000)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**idex.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="htpp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">



<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="css">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="mainStlye.css" />
    </ui:define>

    <!-- to override the content of the content div -->
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="login-form" prependId="false">

            <f:selectedOneMenue value="#{contactBeanTwo.favfood}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{contactBeanTwo.food}"/>
            </f:selectedOneMenue>
            <h:commandButton  value="Submit" actionListener="#{contactBeanTwo.selectedOneMenuMethod()}"/>

        </h:form>

        <h1>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{contactBeanTwo.foodMsg}" rendered="#{not empty contactBeanTwo.foodMsg}" /> 
        </h1>

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>

</html>
```

**ContenBeanTow**

```
package com.beans;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("contactBeanTwo")
@RequestScoped
public class ContactBeanTwo {

    private String foodMsg;
    private String favfood;
    private List<String> food;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        food = Arrays.asList("Hot Dogs", "Hamburgers", "Pizza");

    }

    public String getFoodMsg() {
        return foodMsg;
    }

    public void setFoodMsg(String foodMsg) {
        this.foodMsg = foodMsg;
    }

    public String getFavfood() {
        return favfood;
    }

    public void setFavfood(String favfood) {
        this.favfood = favfood;
    }

    public List<String> getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(List<String> food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public void selectedOneMenuMethod() {
        switch (favfood) {
        case "Piza":
            foodMsg = "Love Pizza!";
            break;

        case "Hot Dogs":
            foodMsg = "Love hot dogs!";
            break;

        case "Hamburgers":
            foodMsg = "Love Hamburgers!";
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use `[jsf]` tag in any JSF question, not just a version specific tag like `[jsf-2.2]`. As to the concrete problem, in which book/tutorial/document/resource exactly have you read about `<f:selectedOneMenue>`?

Comment: Ok it is `<h:selectOneMenu> `